# How to make MPFR to use standard types?

Tags: gmp, mpfr

I'm using MPFR multiple precision library, and in particular the implementation from [here](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/).

Is there any way to compile the code in such a way that all operations are carried out using the standard types (e.g. `double`)? E.g. a compilation flag that would turn all "software operations" into "hardware operations" normally implemented in standard types?

In practice, the code is slow even when I'm using 64 bits, I profiled that the culprit is the mpfr/gmp, and I would like to measure how much I gain by changing to `double` (without having to re-write all the code).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the MPFR library for several reasons. First the formats are different. In particular, MPFR has a different exponent range, no subnormals, a single NaN... Moreover it provides correct rounding in 5 rounding modes, while processors only have 4 rounding modes, and for the native types, most operations are not correctly rounded.

You might want to write wrappers, C++ classes or whatever to do what you want, but this is not necessarily interesting as you may get many conversions between both formats.

EDIT: If you don't care about the exact behavior, perhaps what you want is something based on C++ templates. You probably need to look at another C++ MPFR interface such as [MPFRCPP](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/mpfrcpp/) or [mpfr::real class](http://chschneider.eu/programming/mpfr_real/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the implementation you mention ([MPFR C++](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/) from Pavel Holoborodko) uses operator overloading to make MPFR calls look like standard C float operations, from the site:

```
//MPFR C - version
void mpfr_schwefel(mpfr_t y, mpfr_t x)
{
   mpfr_t t;
   mpfr_init(t);
   mpfr_abs(t,x,GMP_RNDN);
   mpfr_sqrt(t,t,GMP_RNDN);
   mpfr_sin(t,t,GMP_RNDN);
   mpfr_mul(t,t,x,GMP_RNDN);
   mpfr_set_str(y,“418.9829“,10,GMP_RNDN);
   mpfr_sub(y,y,t,GMP_RNDN);
   mpfr_clear(t);
}
```

can be written like this:

```
// MPFR C++ - version
mpreal mpfr_schwefel(mpreal&amp; x)
{
    return  "418.9829"-x*sin(sqrt(abs(x)));
}
```

which is cool by the way, so you just have to make slighty changes like replacing `"418.9829"` by `418.9829`, and comment out MPFR inclusion to your code.

If your code still has remaining `mpfr_...` calls you can get native double-like behaviour by setting the MPFR precision to 53 bits in variable initialization or using, say, specific functions like `mpfr_set_prec`, but note that (as another answer points out), results won't be *exactly* the [same](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html):

> In particular, with a precision of 53 bits and in any of the four standard rounding modes, MPFR is able to exactly reproduce all computations with double-precision machine floating-point numbers (e.g., double type in C, with a C implementation that rigorously follows Annex F of the ISO C99 standard and FP_CONTRACT pragma set to OFF) on the four arithmetic operations and the square root, except the default exponent range is much wider and subnormal numbers are not implemented (but can be emulated).

This might be just good enough for you to have a rough idea of how much MPFR performance differs from native floats.

If that isn't precise enough though, you can place a temporary include into your main file after including MPFR, with `define`s that override the MPFR functions you use, more or less like so:

```
typedef double mpfr_t;
#define mpfr_add(a,b,c,r) {a=b+c;}
```